# WSO2 DAS - Sending multiple events using JSON

Tags: json, wso2, wso2-das

I am trying to send multiple events at once, using JSON, sending the following:

```
{
    "event": {
        "metaData": {
            "meta_timestamp": 4.504343
        },
        "payloadData": {
            "value": 20.44345
        }
    },
    "event": {
        "metaData": {
            "meta_timestamp": 3.57724
        },
        "payloadData": {
            "value": 9.30211
        }
    },
    "event": {
        "metaData": {
            "meta_timestamp": 8.94134
        },
        "payloadData": {
            "value": 35.41315
        }
    }
}
```

Am I using the correct JSON format?

Currently, the event receiver is ready to receive something like this:

```
{
    "event": {
        "metaData": {
            "meta_timestamp": 4.504343
        },
        "payloadData": {
            "value": 20.44345
        }
    }
}
```

I have been reading the documentation, something about "JSON input mapping" but I don't know how to use it ([see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bj9Am.png)).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You JSON input mapping for this purpose. If input JSON is an array, each element will treat as an seperate event. Consider following custom JSON file.

```
[
    {
       "sensorData": {

               "timestamp": 19900813115534,
               "powerSaved": false,
               "id": 501,
               "name": temperature,
               "long": 90.34344,
               "lat": 20.44345,
               "humidity": 2.3,
               "temp": 20.44345
           }
       }
    },
    {
       "sensorData": {
               "timestamp": 19900813115534,
               "powerSaved": false,
               "id": 502,
               "name": temperature,
               "long": 90.34344,
               "lat": 20.44345,
               "humidity": 2.3,
               "temp": 20.44345
           }
       }
    }
]
```

Assume in the stream you have an meta attribute called "isPowerSaverEnabled" to store "powerSaved" attribute of the above JSON. Then in the JSON path should be `$.sensorData.powerSaved` and in the "Mapped to" field it should be `meta_isPowerSaverEnabled`.

For more information refer the documentation [1]. The sample of the this mapping is available with WSO2CEP pack, you can refer that one as well [2]

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS310/Input+Mapping+Types#InputMappingTypes-JSONinputmappingJSONInputMapping

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP410/Sample+0002+-+Receiving+Custom+JSON+Events+via+HTTP+Transport

Comment: Your answer has some syntax errors (two useless '}'). Also, to parse the json array from your example, it does not work properly, it should be something like this: "$..sensorData.powerSaved" (notice the additional point before 'sensorData'). Anyway, your answer helped me to understand the procedure, so I will accept like a valid answer. Thanks!